# Custom authorization for pages in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

How can I create an authorization schema for pages?

For example: I have

- pages like `page1`, `page2`, `page3` and `page4` with
- users as `user1`, `user2`, `user3` and `user4`.

When I login

- user1 should get only page1 and page4
- user2 --> page2 and page3
- user3 --> page1 and page3
- user4 --> page2 and page4

I.e in a `priv` table the page numbers and the users are stored. The boolean return value function is working for components, but for the page it shows an error.

How can I write an authorization schema for the above roles?

Comment: whad did you try so far?

Answer (score 3):

1 - Go to Shared Components

2 - Click on Authorization Schemes

3 - Create a new scheme of the type "PL/SQL function returning boolean"

4 - Your function should return "false" to denied access

In this pl/sql code you have access to :APP_USER variable and :APP_PAGE_ID (page number).

If you have a function that receives the user and the page and return a boolean checking if he has or no access, so just do:

```
BEGIN
   RETURN MYFUNCTION(:APP_USER, :APP_PAGE_ID);
END;
```

5 - Go to "Edit Application Properties" > "Security" and choose your 
authorization scheme.

6 - You don't need to set for every page the authorization scheme, just do the step 5.

[image]

---

I don't know how is your table. But supposing that it's have two columns like

```
USER       PAGE_NUMBER
user1       1
user1       4
user2       2
user2       3
user3       1
user3       3
user4       2
user4       4
```

So your function look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "MYFUNCTION" (p_user IN VARCHAR2, p_page_number IN NUMBER) 
RETURN BOOLEAN AS

v_count NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN

SELECT count(*) INTO v_count
FROM mytable 
WHERE user = p_user AND page_number = p_page_number;

IF v_count = 0 THEN
   RETURN false;
END IF;

RETURN true;

END;
```

Comment: Could you post the code of your function and the pl/sql code that you are using on page authorization scheme? just edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider a custom Authorization Scheme&Authentication Scheme..

1- Create a table for the users to store each user name and password and put a column for 'user_type', in this column you will have the types of users you have for example: 'dev' for developer and 'adm' for admin ans so on ...

2- Create an plsql function that returns a Boolean (true/false) based on
a query that compares the user name and password you get from the user with the ones stored at your users table.
This function will also set 'Session Variables' to pass the user_name and
user_type after a successful login, something like:

```
apex_util.set_session_state('SESSION_U_TYPE',temp_type);

apex_util.set_session_state('SESSION_USER_NAME',in_username);
```

3- At the shared components of your application create 'Application Items' by the same exact names you use in your function (here SESSION_U_TYPE, SESSION_USER_NAME)

4- Edit your 'Log-In' page and remove or comment out the default code and use your function and pass the user_name and password via binding variables

5-Now go to shared components again and create a custom Authorization Scheme, give it a name and choose 'SQL exist' as type and write a sql
query to check the user_type of the current user, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_users 
WHERE user_name = :SESSION_USER_NAME AND user_type = 'dev';
```

Repeat this step to create as many 'access levels' as you need

6- Finally, go to each page and under security section choose the
scheme or the user level you want to allow to access this page

-- Notes:

- - This is fast solution (but working fine) and you can add many improvements to it for example you should create a procedure to handle the log-in and pass the parameters to the authentication function
- - YOU HAVE TO HASH THE PASSWORD AS YOU SHOULD NEVER STORE PASSWORD IN PLAIN TEXT!

I hope this was useful

Answer (score -1):

The above authorization schema with return boolean function works for components if we save the component id along with the page id and check for components

But for page authorization its not working and showing error.
tested with the above table structure and function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrfkw.jpg)

Comment: Could you post the code of your function and the pl/sql code that you are using on page authorization scheme?

Comment: i used the same above function for page authorization